# How can I get CTRL+K CTRL+E to work in terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I don't use these specific control commands in vs code. But I do use them on the terminal all the time.

How can I configure VSCode to send them to the terminal?

When press CTRL+E or CTRL+K, it says:

> waiting for the second key of chord.

CTRL+A works in the terminal just fine, so I figured I'd either have to set something or unset something, but I've had zero luck in tracking that down.

Comment: Might [this](https://dailytechnology.net/windows/2018/05/30/using-gnu-readline-inside-vs-code) help?

Comment: As an aside, when I just tried Ctrl+E, it popped up a toast that mentioned that some keys were dispatched to the Workspace, with a link to (I believe) Settings.  However, I had just picked up a bite of lunch, and by the time I finished it, the message was gone (and seems to have been a one-time).  Timeout on it was very short.